# Are planar symmetry groups and wallpaper groups the same things?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, plane-geometry, symmetry

This is a fairly basic question and an answer will help me make sense as I continue to read up on this topic.

I need to learn about 2D symmetry groups in the context of crystallography and surface science.

I've found two Wikipedia pages:

- [List of planar symmetry groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_planar_symmetry_groups)
- [Wallpaper group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group)

Both groups have 17 members and they have the same [IUC names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Union_of_Crystallography#Symmetry_notation).

**Question:** Are these two articles about two different applications (or users) of the same thing, or are planar symmetry groups and wallpaper groups *different* in some way? For example, can one be applied to dimension number different than 2 and the other can't?

---

Further material that might be helpful for reference...

Symmetry groups:

- https://sites.google.com/a/uw.edu/diffraction-resources/symmetry-resources/2d-symmetry-groups
- http://www.oswego.edu/~baloglou/103/seventeen.html
- http://www.oswego.edu/~baloglou/103/isometrica.html

Wallpaper groups:

- https://www2.clarku.edu/faculty/djoyce/wallpaper/seventeen.html
- http://www.tessellations.org/tess-escher7.shtml
- https://mathstat.slu.edu/escher/index.php/Wallpaper_Patterns

Comment: slightly related: [Is the completeness of the 230 known space groups in three dimensions proven?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3797248/284619)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of [planar symmetry groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_planar_symmetry_groups) contains the $17$ wallpaper groups ($2$-dimensional crystallographic groups), but also $7$ frieze groups and $2$ families of rosette groups *in addition*.

The symmetry groups listed are the classes of discrete symmetry groups of the Euclidean plane. The crystallographic ones are *cocompact*, i.e., $\Bbb R^2/\Gamma$ is compact, where $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of $Isom(\Bbb R^2)$. These are called *wallpaper groups* and the classification up to abstract isomorphism (or conjugacy in the affine group) yields $17$ different groups.

Comment: thank you for the speedy answer; I should have caught the first part, but nonetheless this helps