# Number of possible rotational domains of one 2D lattice on top of another?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, integer-lattices

There are four (or five) [two dimensional Bravais lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice#In_2_dimensions) which I refer to as *oblique, rectangular, hexagonal* and *square*.

I'll discuss the 17 symmetry [wallpaper groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group) below.

Ignoring translation, if I ask someone to lay one hexagonal lattice on top of another with one of their axes parallel, there's only one distinct rotational way to do it. One might think there are six (since the lattice is p6 or six-fold rotationally symmetric) but they are indistinguishable.

If I ask for an offset of 10 degrees then there are two ways (+/- 10°).

If I ask for an offset of 60/2 = 30 degrees, the number of ways drops back to one.

The expression or algorithm I need would fill out the following table:

```
                   Oblique   Rectangular   Hexagonal     Square
                      2           2            6            3

Oblique      2       1/1

Rectangular  2

Hexagonal    6       3/6 (30)              1/2 (30)

Square       4                                          1/2 (45)
```

**This is read as follows:** For hexagonal on hexagonal every 30 degrees there is 1 way, and for angles that are non-zero modulus 30 degrees there are 2 ways. For square on hexagonal the number is three and six, also every 30 degrees as shown here

Square and hexagonal lattices shown separately:

[image: square and hexagonal lattices shown separately]

Square and hexagonal lattices shown at 0, 30 and 60 degrees:

[image: square and hexagonal lattices shown at 0, 30 and 60 degrees]

Square and hexagonal lattices shown at +/-10 degrees (only two of the possible six are shown):

[image: square and hexagonal lattices shown at +/-10 degrees]

---

In surface science if we had islands of one lattice on top of another that different only in this way we'd call them **domains.**

**Question:** For pairs of 2D lattices each with either a 2, 3, 4 or 6-fold rotational symmetry (ten possible pairs in total), how can I calculate the number of possible ways I can uniquely configure them with a given angle who's absolute value is $\theta$.

This is of course likely to be a solved problem, so if one wants to point me to a description of the solution that is not written at a high level rather than doing so here, that would also be great!

### Wallpaper

The problem is more complex if the specific symmetry group of each lattice is defined and if that can be included in the answer at the same time it will be even more helpful. I'm not sure how to formulate that question exactly so I've ask the question who's answer will at least get me started.

- [Are planar symmetry groups and wallpaper groups the same things?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3551143/284619)

Comment: Pardon any incorrect or inexact use of math words, feel free to query or correct as needed.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you for the help with the tagging. Since then I've edited the question a bit and added some more explanation.

Comment: **update:** I know the answer to this now, and it is simpler than the question makes it look. I'll post an answer in the next day or two.