# Is the completeness of the 230 known space groups in three dimensions proven?

Tags: math-history, symmetric-groups, symmetry

Wikipedia's [Space group; History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_group#History) includes the passage below. While it mentions a proof for the 17 wallpaper groups in two dimensions, the word "proof" doesn't occur again in the article.

Is it settled now that there are exactly 230 possible space groups in three dimensions; that the current list is correct *and complete?*

If so, is it possible to cite a formal proof of this?

---

> **Space groups in 2 dimensions are the 17 wallpaper groups which have been known for several centuries, though the proof that the list was complete was only given in 1891, after the much more difficult classification of space groups had largely been completed.** In 1879 the German mathematician Leonhard Sohncke listed the 65 space groups (called Sohncke groups) whose elements preserve the chirality. More accurately, he listed 66 groups, but both the Russian mathematician and crystallographer Evgraf Fedorov and the German mathematician Arthur Moritz Schoenflies noticed that two of them were really the same. The space groups in three dimensions were first enumerated in 1891 by Fedorov (whose list had two omissions (I43d and Fdd2) and one duplication (Fmm2)), and shortly afterwards in 1891 were independently enumerated by Schönflies (whose list had four omissions (I43d, Pc, Cc, ?) and one duplication (P421m)). The correct list of 230 space groups was found by 1892 during correspondence between Fedorov and Schönflies. Barlow (1894) later enumerated the groups with a different method, but omitted four groups (Fdd2, I42d, P421d, and P421c) even though he already had the correct list of 230 groups from Fedorov and Schönflies; the common claim that Barlow was unaware of their work is incorrect. Burckhardt (1967) describes the history of the discovery of the space groups in detail.

Comment: I don't think the `solution-verification` fits, but I don't see a tag for "is there a proof for..."

Comment: slightly related: [Are planar symmetry groups and wallpaper groups the same things?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3551143/284619)

Comment: A formal proof like https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-39634-2_14 ? I'd doubt that. I suspect your best bet is to find the Burckhardt reference.

Comment: @AnginaSeng so while there's general agreement that there are 230, there's no proof that there can't be more? btw [Zur Geschichte der Entdeckung der 230 Raumgruppen](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00412962) is not in English so I'll have to look for a translation

Comment: I'm sure this is as rigorously proved as any well-known but non-trivial theorem. I doubt whether it has been formalised and checked in a theorem-verifying language such as Coq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new algebraic solution has also been given, based on the Zassenhaus algorithm to determine the conjugacy classes of finite subgroups of $GL_3(\Bbb Z)$. The result is again $219$, respectively $230$ if we distinguish between
mirror images. So there can't be "more".

References:
[An Algebraic Classification of the Three-Dimensional
Crystallographic Groups](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/019688589190002Z/pdf?md5=86b8e0eb1484cf0c751bcf1833a35aab&pid=1-s2.0-019688589190002Z-main.pdf)

[Counting crystallographic groups in low dimensions](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1045604675)

Comment: Note that the Wikiepdia page states that even this computer-based proof is wrong in dimension 6...

Comment: I see. But I believe that in dimension $3$ the result is correct (many people checked this independently).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to cast doubt on the 3-dimensional case. It was more a 'math is hard' comment. It's so hard to do this stuff in an error-free way.

Comment: No problem. I totally agree. Similar problems come with other classifications results.

Comment: Tell me about it. I am currently classifying maximal subgroups of exceptional groups of Lie type. A significant portion of that is correcting past lists of maximal subgroups.

Comment: I worked on semisimple subalgebras of semisimple Lie algebras and had some problems with Dynkin's list...

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you for your answer! Since I'm not a mathematician, the "So there can't be 'more'" is appreciated! As an aside Auslander and Cook refers to [Johnson](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0196885891900032) in the same volume for the "relation of our results to the standard presentation of crystallographic groups".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, Conway et al. did it in a new way in the *Beitraege*. See the references in the Wikipedia article.

A pdf can be found [here](https://www.emis.de//journals/BAG/vol.42/no.2/b42h2con.pdf).

Comment: I see that the authors call this an "enumeration" and that word appears 17 times throughout. Is there any aspect of this paper that asserts that *these are all that there can be, there can be no more*, or cites a work that does so?  Right now I'm not seeing how this is more than *these are all that we can currently think of, we can't see how there could be any more*. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh Enumeration here means listing all of the objects, not all of the known objects. It appears to give a full proof, although I have not checked in detail.

Comment: I see. In plain language; one wouldn't presume to properly enumerate until one is confident that there are no others, and so an enumeration will go to some lengths to demonstrate that *these are all there can be*. But one can't explicitly say there can't be any others and get it past peer review without a proof or citation thereof. And since there wasn't one and this is not one, they didn't?

Comment: Why do you think this enumeration does not contain a proof that there are no others?

Comment: Read it? I mean, that's the usual way. For example, section 2.1 contains a proof that their enumeration of irreducible groups is complete.

Comment: Okay I'll dig in; let's see what others think as well.